# Dockerを使用してWordpressを構築すると、mysqlに接続できないうえにメモリ使用率が異常なほど高くなる。

Tags: mysql, docker, wordpress

OSはManjaroがインストールされたローカルPCに、Dockerを使ってWordpressをインストールしようとしています。
DockerおよびDocker-composeは、Manjaroに付属のソフトウェアの追加と削除を使って、extraリポジトリからインストールしました。

https://prograshi.com/wordpress/docker-wordpress/

環境構築は、上記サイトに従って行いました。

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

「docker-compose up -d」を実行後、WordpressのURLである「localhost:10090」にアクセスすると、「Warning: mysqli_real_connect(): (HY000/2002): Connection refused in /var/www/html/wp-includes/class-wpdb.php on line 1987 」というエラーが発生して、wordpressのインストールに進むことができません。

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

また、mysqlが起動している間、PCのメモリ使用率が異常に高くなってしまい、あらゆる処理が遅くなってしまいます。
数分後にはメモリ使用率が落ちて軽くなるのですが、そのときにはmysqlが勝手に終了されていました。

よって今回解決したいこととしましては、

- wordpressのインストール画面でConnection refusedエラーが発生する
- mysqlのメモリ使用率が高すぎる
- mysqlが強制終了してしまう

解決方法をご存知の方がいらっしゃいましたら、よろしくお願いします。